# Appendices in REVTeX 4.1

Tags: appendices, revtex

How does one get into appendix mode when using the \prl option in the documentclass? According to the instructions you put `\appendix` into the code and everything following is treated as an appendix. But this doesn't seem to do anything, nor does `\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}`.

Comment: What exactly have you tried to see if `\appendix` is working or not? Ideally you would add a complete minimal but compilable example that showcases your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `prl` option enabled in the declaration of the documentclass, there are no section numbers, including appendix prefixes. With this option removed, they appear normally.

Comment: To which call of the `prl` option do you refer?

Comment: It's in the documentclass. Found this when my other problem with section references was addressed.

Comment: I know :) Still, in the OP there is no clue that the meant option is in use (due to a missing MWE!).